# LuaJIT -- "ngx" module isn't found. Should I install it?

Tags: nginx, lua, luajit

I'm trying to create a Hello World in Lua using **LuaJit** for nginx. When I run a script:

```
luajit my_test.lua
```

I get this:

```
luajit: my_test.lua: attempt to index global 'ngx' (a nil value)
```

Do I have to install a library? I've already tried "luarocks install " with "ngx", "nginx", "ngx_lua" and some others -- they weren't found.

```
Error: No results matching query were found.
```

Why isn't it getting found? Should I install a module at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngx` is not a part of Lua, so it cannot be found. It also isn't possible to just install it as a library.

The only place where `ngx` can be used is inside [openresty](https://openresty.org/en/).